# How to produce intentional encoding errors in u"..." strings?

Tags: c, utf-16, string-literals

I am writing a UTF-16 decode routine.  To check if it works correctly, I need to produce test strings with intentional encoding errors in them.  However, when I try to produce such strings in C the obvious way, the compiler rejects my code with “... is not a valid universal character:”

```
u"\ud800" /* unmatched low surrogate */
u"\udc01\ud802" /* surrogates in wrong order */
```

How can I produce `u"..."` strings with intentional encoding errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\uXXXX` and `\UXXXXXXXX` escape sequences can only encode valid universal characters.  To encode other `char16_t` values, use a `\x...` escape sequence:

```
u"\xd800" /* unmatched low surrogate */
u"\xdc01\xd802" /* surrogates in wrong order */
```